# How to set encrypted files to Hibernate 3.x

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption, jdbc, struts2

How to set encrypted Username and password files to the hibernate config file?

Usually In JDBC we used to decrypt the password and pass them to the JDBC.

But I struck here how to do that in hibernate.. Is there any special API for that purpose in Hibernate or I need to use any third party Library?

Comment: Do you need to encrypt credentials used to connect to hibernate, or do you need to ecnrypt credentials stored inside hibernate, or do you need to ecnrypt the whole hibernate storage?

Comment: I have encrypted files with me ... I need hibernate to read encrypted files